# Collision resolution issues with circles

Tags: c++, collision-detection, direct2d

I have a small application I have built where there are a few balls on a blank background. They all start flying through the air and use the physics I wrote to bounce accurately and have realistic collision responses. I am satisfied with how it looks except I have an issue where when my balls land directly on top of each other, the attach together and float directly up.

Here are the functions involved

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/899d6fb255a85d8f2102

Basically if the Collision function returns true, I use the ResolveCollision to change their velocities accordingly.

I believe the issue is from the slight re-positioning I do in ResolveCollision(). If they collide I bring them a frame or so backwards in location so that they are not intersecting still the next frame. However, when they are directly on top they bounce off eachother at such small bounces that eventually stepping back a frame isn't enough to unhook them.

I'm unsure if this is the problem and if it is, then what to do about it.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to ignore the collision if the circles are moving away from each other. This works so long as your timestep is small enough relative to their velocities (i.e. the circles can't pass through each other in a single frame).

When the circles first collide, you will adjust their velocity vectors so their relative velocity vector pushes them apart (because a collision will do that). After that, any further collisions are spurious because the circles will be moving apart, and will eventually separate completely. So, just ignore collisions between objects that are moving apart, and you should be fine.

(I've implemented such an algorithm in a 3D screensaver I wrote, but the algorithm is entirely dimension-agnostic and so would work fine for 2D circles).

Comment: Ah! This makes so much sense! To check that they are moving away from each other would be to dot their velocities correct? And if the result is negative they're heading away from eachother?

Comment: Not quite. In fact, you want to dot the relative position vector against the relative velocity vector. This tells you if the relative velocity vector is in the same direction as the position vector (=> moving away) or in opposite direction as the position vector (=> moving towards).

Comment: Would it be one object's position vs the other's velocity? Or their own position dotted by their own velocity?

Comment: *Relative* position and velocity: that is, one object's position/velocity minus the other object's position/velocity.